# Directory Structure for Cucumber + Maven + POM project under SRC & TEST folder

Tags: maven, selenium, project-management, directory-structure

I am looking for effective project Structure to manage it with POM, Cucumber(Feature and Step definition Files) under Maven's Src & test folders.

What should be correct way to manage? Where to use Maven's src and test folder.

Please Share. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Project Structure for a Maven project with Cucumber + POM**

[image: Project Structure]

**base package** contains Page object initialization class where it can be extended to all the page classes

**browser package** contains the browser factory class which contains the methods to invoke Chrome, Firefox, IE etc.,

**custom Exception package** used to throw the custom messages

**features package** contains the feature files

**pages package** contains the page objects classes like login, home page with the relevant web elements and methods

**resources package** contains the driver information, test data information, xml configuration, property file etc.,

**runner package** contains the runner classes which is created in manual. Otherwise we can refer the same package for dynamic runner class creation in maven parallel plugin dependency.

**steps package** contains the step definition for each specific pages.

**utils package** contains the utility classes like common utility, selenium utility, excel utility etc.,

**Under target**

*cucumber - parallel* contains the parallel execution report

*cucumber-reports* contains the normal execution report

*generated-test-sources* contains the dynamic runner class files which is created during the run time for parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

feature files are not java code and should be in src\test\resources folder