# Structure of an automation framework components in Maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, automation

I have developed a cucumber based selenium automation framework and have used Page Object with Page Factory as the design pattern for it. 
Below are different components of my automation framework :

1. Page Objects.
2. POJOs
3. sharedutilities
4. Feature Files
5. Config file
6. Expected Data folder
7. Extent config.xml
8. chromedriver.exe
9. Reports folder

I am not entirely satisfied with the way I have arranged these components inside maven project. There are multiple source folder for Maven like src/test/java, src/main/java, src/test/resources, src/main/resources, are there some standard set of guidelines on what to put inside these 4 folders depending on the components which I have mentioned above ?

Comment: This link would be helpful for you. [Structure of Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401626/4197679)

Comment: There seems to be only one folder, src/test/java in this link and everything is placed inside it.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan resources folder could have been placed inside src/test/resources instead of src/test/java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General guidelines:

- `src/main/java` contains your application code (.java files)
- `src/main/resources` contains any non-code files that go with your application. for instance property files or config files for your application (if they are not Java config files, like your config.xml).
- `src/test/java` contains any test code (.java files) for your application. If you mirror your package structure from `src/main/java` testing frameworks like Junit can automatically find the right classes to test without having to specify imports for them. In the case of Cucumber, this is where your step definitions go, as well as any other code that helps you perform your Cucumber tests (like the Page Objects in your example).
- `src/test/resources` contains any non code files that go with your tests. In the case of Cucumber, this is where the feature files go. If you have a separate test config.xml that would go here.

If you have only test code, you might not have a `src/main` folder. I'd recommend locating your test code in the same repository as the system you're going to test, as this will make it easier to get fast feedback.

Regarding your question:

1. Page Objects -> `src/test/java`
2. POJOs - depending on whether they are application POJOs or test POJOs -> `src/main/java` or `src/test/java` respectively
3. sharedutilities - asusming this is code to help your tests -> `src/test/java`
4. Feature Files -> `src/test/resources`
5. Config file -> depends on whether this is for the application or test, and whether its code or xml.
6. Expected Data folder - not sure what you mean. Test files (like .json or something) might go in `src/test/resources`
7. Extent config.xml - probably `src/test/resources`
8. chromedriver.exe - might go in your root directory. (I might recommend against including .exe in your project; how are you going to deal with different OS?)
9. Reports folder -> would probably go to a target folder?

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. According to the above answer, src/main/java would not have any test code. So while developing a test automation framework, no code should go to src/main/java or src/man resources right ?

Comment: How about the output that is spitted out by my code for eg. screenshots, where should I place these ?

Comment: screenshots should go with test reports, somewhere in the target directory imho

Comment: If reports stored in target folder, wouldn't reports be deleted with each mvn build ?